# AWStats Unknown File Type

Tags: html, file, drupal, types, awstats

When I generate reports for AWStats for my Drupal site, the top File Type is "Unknown."  This accounts for 80% of hits.  I assume this is because many pages end in "/" or are extensionless (know problem with Drupal and AWStats).  My question is, can I default ALL of the "Unknown" file types to HTML?

Thanks.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If this is not possible, that'd be good to know also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot set a Default File Type, but you can change the name from "Unknown" to something else.

Modified the AWStats core code to show "Drupal Node" instead of "Unknown" for Drupal File Types.
Line 10563 of awstats.pl

Original code:
`<td class=\"aws\" colspan=\"2\"><span style=\"color: #$color_other\">$Message[1]</span></td>";`

New code:
`<td class=\"aws\" colspan=\"2\"><span style=\"color: #$color_other\">Drupal Node</span></td>";`